# How to use range of escape sequences in sed?

Tags: sed, range

I need to look for a wide range of characters like this but I got an error like out of range on character 27.

```
output=$(sed -E "s/([\u05BD-\u05BF]+)/*\1*/g" <<< "$input")
```

Why doesn't this syntax work? Or how to correctly search for the range of characters. These are hebrew characters.

```
input="עֲטֶרֶת גֵּאוּת שִׁכּוֹרֵי אֶפְרָיִם׃Genesis
 וְהָיְתָה צִיצַת נֹבֵל צְבִי תִפְאַרְתּוֹ kapitola 3 אֲשֶׁר kapitola 2 עַל־רֹאשׁ גֵּיא שְׁמָנִים כְּבִכּוּרָהּ בְּטֶרֶם קַיִץ אֲשֶׁר יִרְאֶה Jozue  הָרֹאֶה kapitola 4 אוֹתָהּ בְּעוֹדָהּ בְּכַפּוֹ יִבְלָעֶנָּה"
output=$(sed -E "s/([\u05BD-\u05BF]+)/*\1*/g" <<< "$input")
echo "$input"
```

I try to replace a segment of characters in hebrew and add a asterix on the end of the block.

Expected result:

```
input="עֲטֶרֶת גֵּאוּת שִׁכּוֹרֵי אֶפְרָיִם׃*Genesis
 וְהָיְתָה צִיצַת נֹבֵל צְבִי תִפְאַרְתּוֹ *kapitola 3* אֲשֶׁר *kapitola 2*עַל־רֹאשׁ גֵּיא שְׁמָנִים כְּבִכּוּרָהּ בְּטֶרֶם קַיִץ אֲשֶׁר יִרְאֶה Jozue*  הָרֹאֶה *kapitola 4* אוֹתָהּ בְּעוֹדָהּ בְּכַפּוֹ יִבְלָעֶנָּה"
```

Comment: 5.9.3 in the [GNU sed docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Locale-Considerations.html) reads to me like there is no warranty on the "sorting sequence behavior" for locales other than, well, latinate ones.  Because it seems to indicate French might work.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to put an `*` around the `katitola`, including the numbers.

This seems to do that:

```
output=$(sed -E "s/([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{2,})/*\1*/g" <<< "$input")
```

It find 2, or more, non-Hebrew characters (including space and numbers) and surround them with an `*`.

Comment: `[\P{Hebrew}]` could mean not-hebrew?

Comment: @stevesliva doesn't quite seem to work: `echo "$input" | sed -E 's/[\p{Block=Hebrew}\p{Script_Extensions=Hebrew}\p{Line_Break=Hebrew_Letter}\p{Word_Break=Hebrew}]+/(&)/g'`

Comment: @Luuk, thank you for your answer, but I gave up on sed. awk is more regex friendly. I used it to do what I needed.

Comment: @JohnBoe glad you solved your problem. you should add your solution as an answer to help other people

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for me was to use awk. I defined the non-hebrew characters which I am using. So I included latin and some Slovanian characters. It may be needed to add digits too.

```
function addStarBeforeNonHebrewChar(word) {
# Definition of non hebrew characters in hebrew segment been found:
  if (match(word, /[a-zA-Z\\dŠšáéíóú]/)) {
    position = RSTART - 1
    word = substr(word, 1, position) "*" substr(word, position + 1)
    return word "*"
  }
  else {
    return word
  }
}
```

Cool trick to make things faster is to check the first character if it is hebrew:

```
if (substr(word, 1, 1) ~ /^[א-ת]/) {
    word = addStarBeforeNonHebrewChar(word)
    result = result word
  }
```

I checked the word for cases when hebrew and latin text have no separator like  word="טֶרֶת גֵּאוּת שִׁכּוֹרֵי אֶפְרָיִם׃Genesis"